# Solving functional equations with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let us consider the functional equation

[image]

Mathematically, we know how to solve that equation in closed form, but what if we look for an approximate solution `f` in the form of a fully-connected 1 or 2-layer neural network with relu activation function?

What is the best way in Tensorflow to do a gradient descent on

[image]

for mini-batches of `x's` drawn randomly in [-10,10] ?
My question arises from the fact that there is both `f(x)` and `f(x+1)` in the equation, and that differs from classical supervised learning.

Comment: Changed tex syntax to equivalent images. Hope it is right.

Comment: Thank you @Mohan Radhakrishnan, I did not know it did not work like in stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to simply run through the network with `x+1` as well. That is, for a two-layer network, you could have a model that looks as follows:

```
num_units_layer_1 = 200
num_units_layer_2 = 200

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

seed = 42

weights = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, num_units_layer_1], seed=seed)),
    'hidden2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units_layer_1, num_units_layer_2], seed=seed)),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units_layer_2, 1], seed=seed))
}

biases = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units_layer_1], seed=seed)),
    'hidden2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units_layer_2], seed=seed)),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1], seed=seed))
}

def model_f(x):
    hidden_layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['hidden1']), biases['hidden1'])
    hidden_layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer_1)
    hidden_layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_layer_1, weights['hidden2']), biases['hidden2'])
    hidden_layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer_2)
    return tf.matmul(hidden_layer_2, weights['output']) + biases['output']

output_layer = model_f(x)
output_layerp = model_f(x+1)

in_range = tf.logical_and(x >= 0, x <= 1)
target_x = tf.where(in_range, output_layer, x)

cost = tf.reduce_mean((output_layerp - output_layer - x**2)**2) + tf.reduce_mean((target_x - x)**2)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

Then, when estimating the parameters you can simply generate batches as you go:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Estimate
    for epoch in range(5000):
        sample = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (400, 1))
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: sample})
        if epoch % 1000 == 999:
            print(f'Epoch {epoch}, cost: {c}')

    # Make predictions and plot result
    xs = np.linspace(-10, 10, 500).reshape(500, 1)
    predictions = sess.run(output_layer, feed_dict={x: xs})
    plt.plot(xs, predictions)
```

This generates the following output:

[image]

We can compare this with what you get by simply using the functional equation to define *f* recursively:

```
def f(x):
    if x >= 0 and x <= 1:
        return x
    if x > 1:
        return f(x-1) + (x-1)**2
    if x < 0:
        return f(x+1) - x**2

plt.plot(xs, [f(x[0]) for x in xs])
plt.plot(xs, predictions)
```

[image]

Pretty much spot on. It doesn't generalize to other ranges though:

[image]